# What's the purpose of transient function variables?

Tags: apex

I came across the following snippet of code, and I wondered what purpose it may have, or if none, why Salesforce would even allow this to compile:

```
void BindData(Integer newPage) {
    Transient Integer counter = 0;
    Transient Integer min = 0;
    Transient Integer max = 0;
    // Calculate min/max, then loop using counter
```

Since the purpose of `transient` is to avoid serialization, it doesn't seem to make sense that you could mark variables within a function as transient, since you can't serialize functions (or, can you?).

I've already optimized this code away with something more efficient, I just wanted to know what possible use transient might have in this context.

Comment: Aesthetics? If the types had been something large in the heap I might have guessed something undocumented to do with garbage collection. More likely they used to be defined as instance variables on the class and were refactored into the method without dropping the keyword.

Comment: An off-hand comment from the author of MavensMate was that Salesforce were not willing to share the BNF for Apex. Maybe whoever wrote the compiler didn't get to see it either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd assume nothing, transient makes absolutely no sense for local variables. APEX has enough bizarre idiosyncrasies that I'd put my money on this just being an oversight rather than an intentional feature.

Comment: This would be my guess as well.